# Why ++i, i++ are the same in for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < n+1; ++i)
{
    sum = sum + i;
}

for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++)
{
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

Two paragraphs are different because of ++i and i++ in function call argument.

but it works like i only starts with 0. Why does even ++i starts with 0?

Comment: "n function call argument" There are no functions in your code, what are you talking about?

Comment: @r3mainer Bad duplicate. In other languages prefix vs postfix might matter, for example C++ with operator overloading.

Comment: Please create a [mre] to show us. For example, how do you initialize the variable `sum`?

Comment: Also note that there are no function calls in the shown code, and there are no arguments. `for` is a *statement* which uses three (optional) expressions. And as mentioned by @Lundin in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70682465/440558) there's absolutely no practical difference between the two loops. The only possible problem is in the code you *don't* show us (and very likely the initialization, or perhaps the lack of initialization, of `sum`).

Comment: _"for loop produces different value in C"_: no it doesn't. Did you even try this?

Comment: Sorry guys I would have liked to show you guys only the small piece of it to make the point.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The title is totally messed up. I meant that "no difference between them"

Comment: @JGPARK you can [edit] your question including the title

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes I edited the title. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: In both cases the condition should be `i <= n` rather than `i < n+1`.

Comment: @Cheatah Why is that?

Comment: Because `i <= n` is on most architectures a single operation while `i < n+1` requires some arithmetic every loop. That could be optimised out by the compiler, but why rely on that. Besides that, the intention of my condition is clearer.

Comment: @Cheatah Makes sense. Thanks a lot for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are absolutely no difference between these two snippets. `i++` vs `++i` only matters when mixed with other operators in the same expression. Which is a bad idea most of the time, since `i++`/`++i` comes with a side effect.

Answer (score 1):

A generic `for` loop like

```
for (a; b; c)
{
    d
}
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    a;
    while (b)
    {
        d;
        c;
    }
}
```

Note how the "increment" expression `c` is *after* the main statement of the loop body.

For your loops that means they will be equivalent to:

```
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n+1)
    {
        sum = sum + i;
        i++;  // or ++i
    }
}
```

Since the increment of `i` doesn't happen until *after* you calculate `sum` there's no practical difference between the loops. Both will lead to the exact same result.

---

On a side-note: Remember to explicitly initialize `sum` to zero before the loop, or it might have an *indeterminate* value (that could be seen as garbage).

Answer (score 0):

The two for loops you posted will behave exactly the same.  The reason they are equivalent, which also answers your question of why both loops start from `0`, is that the increment (`i++` or `++i`) only happens **after** the *{expression}* in {} has executed, and after *every* time it has executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would produce identical results.

The following code would produce different results.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
  printf("%d\n", ++i);
}
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
  printf("%d\n", i++);
}
// 0
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
```

In my example the reason the bottom for-loop prints out 0 and the top for-loop doesn't is because `printf` and `i++/++i` form a combined expression where in the top `i` is incremented and then accessed from memory whereas in the bottom loop `i` is access from memory and then incremented.

Answer (score 0):

The `i++` and `++i` expressions in the last clause of these `for` loops both increment `i` as a side effect and since the value of the expression is not used, they have exactly the same effect, namely the side effect.

Here are other alternative, all of which behave the same and should produce the same code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i += 1) {
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i = i + 1) {
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

Note however that if `n` is an `int` with the value `INT_MAX`, `n+1` has undefined behavior. A safer way to write this loop is:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum = sum + i;
}
```

But the `<=` operator has the same problem when `n` is `INT_MAX`: the undefined behavior would occur on the `i++` part when `i` reaches `INT_MAX`...

Here is an alternative that avoids this corner case:

```
if (n > 0) {
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    sum = sum + n;
}
```